# Relationship to different tables in SQLalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, one-to-many

I have multiple tables. All tables have multiple columns that could not logically be stored in one merged table.

```
class Foo(Model):
    foo_id = Column(Integer(unsigned=True), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    foo_data = Column(...)

class Bar(Model):
    bar_id = Column(Integer(unsigned=True), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    bar_info = Column(...)

class Baz(Model):
    baz_id = Column(Integer(unsigned=True), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    baz_content = Column(...)
```

Now I want to save changes in a history table:

```
class Diff(Model):
    diff_id = Column(...)
    foreign_id = Column(Integer(unsigned=True), index=True, nullable=False)
    foreign_table = Column(Char(16, collation='ascii_bin'), index=True, nullable=False)

class SingleDiff(Model):
     ...
     diff = relationship(Diff, backref=backref('changes', uselist=True, ...))
```

Now my problem is: **How can I populate `Diff.foreign_id` in the same commit when inserting a new `Foo`, `Bar`, or `Baz`?**

This works, but if there should be a problem to insert the `Diff` then it is too late to rollback the changes to `foo`:

```
foo = Foo(foo_data='TODO: changes table names')
try:
    session.add(foo)
    session.commit()  # first commit
except ...:
    ....
else:
    try:
         diff = Diff(changes=[...])
         diff.foreign_id = foo.foo_id
         diff.foerein_table = 'foo'
         session.add(diff)
         session.commit()  # second commit
     except ...:
         raise Exception('Cannot rollback commit #1 anymore :-(')
```

For normal relationships the id is inserted automagically:

```
class FooDiff(Model):
    diff_id = Column(...)
    foo_id = Column(Integer(unsigned=True), ForeignKey(...), ...)
    foo = relationship(Foo)
```

But I don't have `Diff.foo`, because `Diff.foreign_id` could point to many different tables.

Comment: Take a read of [Generic Associations](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/examples.html#module-examples.generic_associations) section of the documentation. I think that especially [Generic Foreign Key](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/_modules/examples/generic_associations/generic_fk.html) example should be suitable for your case.

Comment: @van, thank you for the links!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I came up with is almost the same as that what [@van](https://stackoverflow.com/users/99594/van) has linked: [ORM Examples: Generic Associations](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/examples.html#module-examples.generic_associations).

```
def _foreign_id_rel(Cls):
    return relationship(
        Cls,
        uselist=False,
        lazy=False,  # This is just my use case, not needed
        primaryjoin=lambda: and_(
            Diff.foreign_table == Cls.__tablename__,
            foreign(Diff.foreign_id) == Cls.id,
        ),
        backref=backref(
            'diffs',
            uselist=True,
            lazy=True,  # This is just my use case, not needed
            primaryjoin=lambda: and_(
                Diff.foreign_table == Cls.__tablename__,
                foreign(Diff.foreign_id) == Cls.id,
            ),
        ),
    )


class Diff(Model):
    ...

    foo = _foreign_id_rel(Foo)
    bar = _foreign_id_rel(Bar)
    baz = _foreign_id_rel(Baz)

    @property
    def foreign(self):
        if self.foreign_table:
            return getattr(self, self.foreign_table)

    @foreign.setter
    def foreign(self, value):
        if value is None:
            self.foreign_table = None
            self.foreign_id = None
        else:
            tbl_name = value.__tablename__
            self.foreign_table = tbl_name
            setattr(self, tbl_name, value)
```