# Multiple foreign keys in the same column SqlAlchemy python Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

How to I create a foreign key column that has multiple foreign keys in it?  I have a notes table that I would like to keep notes in for many different subjects/tables.  I.e. someone can keep a note against a user or a service.

In the model that I have created below, the f_key keeps the foreign keys and the table name tells us which foreign key to join on, just not sure how to setup the sqlalchemy relationship

```
from datetime import datetime


class NoteModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "app_note"
    note_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    table_name = db.Column(db.String)
    f_key = db.Column(db.Integer)
    note = db.Column(db.Text)
    created_timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now())
    updated_timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now())
```

UPDATE
Have tried the solutions that people have commented on but still getting an error, my attempt:
Notes:

```
from db.db import db
from datetime import datetime
from utilities.model_tools import foreign_id_rel
# from models.person import PersonModel

def _foreign_id_rel(foreign_model_name, foreign_table_name, foreign_table_primary_key
                    , ref_name):
    return db.relationship(
        foreign_model_name,
        primaryjoin=f"""and_(foreign(NoteModel.f_key)=={foreign_model_name}.{foreign_table_primary_key}, NoteModel.table_name == {foreign_table_name})""",
        backref=db.backref(
            ref_name,
            primaryjoin=f"""and_(foreign(NoteModel.f_key)=={foreign_model_name}.{foreign_table_primary_key}, NoteModel.table_name == {foreign_table_name})""",
        ),
    )


class NoteModel(db.Model):
    """Keeps notes for all entities"""
    __tablename__ = "app_note"
    note_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    table_name = db.Column(db.String)
    f_key = db.Column(db.Integer, index=True)
    note = db.Column(db.Text)
    created_timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now())
    updated_timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now())

    person = _foreign_id_rel('PersonModel', 'app_person', 'person_id', 'note')
```

person model:

```
from db.db import db
from datetime import datetime
from models.user import UserModel
from models.contact_details import ContactDetailsModel
from models.staff_member import StaffMemberModel
from models.client_details import ClientDetailsModel
from models.person_service import PersonServiceModel
from models.notes import NoteModel


class PersonModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'app_person'
    person_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    date_of_birth = db.Column(db.Date)
    created_timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now())
    updated_timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now())

    user = db.relationship("UserModel", uselist=False, back_populates='person')
    contact_details = db.relationship('ContactDetailsModel', uselist=False, back_populates="person")
    staff_member = db.relationship('StaffMemberModel', uselist=False, back_populates='person')
    client_details = db.relationship('ClientDetailsModel', uselist=False, back_populates='person')
    service = db.relationship('PersonServiceModel', back_populates='person')
    notes = db.relationship('NoteModel', backref=db.backref(
        'person',
        primaryjoin=f"""and_(foreign(NoteModel.f_key)==PersonModel.person_id, NoteModel.table_name == {__tablename__})"""
    ))
```

The error that I am currently getting is:

```
Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship PersonModel.notes - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing column
s are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.
```

Which I understand that it isn't happy that I haven't given it a Foreign key on the notes table but I can't really do that but it also seems to have missed that I have given it a primaryjoin condition?  Or have I done that wrong somehow?

Comment: Though a bit of an antipattern, are you perhaps after a "generic foreign key / association": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32570645/relationship-to-different-tables-in-sqlalchemy/32583267#32583267 ? I think you could also model this using *{ note_id, <target_id> }* per target relations as well, removing the need for the generic foreign key, but you might find handling multiple association relations/tables off-putting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relationship to different tables in SQLalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32570645/relationship-to-different-tables-in-sqlalchemy)